# How to push CheckmarX report to Defectdojo

Tags: checkmarx

I was trying to push CheckmarX report to Defectdojo using Jenkins
Searched for the solution but unable to find any.

Manually uploaded the report to defectdojo but i was want to send report directly to defectdojo using API